# Need help for Mysql selected query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field on database, the name is `Time_message`, and I set default for this date is `w, d-m-Y H:i:s`, and I wanna create some search using BETWEEN and a value just show "d-m-Y" how can i show it to my query??

I bring my code below..

```
$date1 = "21-08-2015";
$date2 = "d-m-Y";
$query = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as jumlahdata FROM message_complaint WHERE (status_message='".$data['status_message']."') AND (time_message BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2)"));
```

Comment: nothing error, but a value always show 0

Comment: @bayucakra check the answer below

Comment: i wanna select data on table time_message, but i set a format date is "w, d-m-Y H:i:s", now i create a datepicker to set range of date, but i set this format date just "d-m-Y", how can i select using BETWEEN on my query??

Answer (score 0):

you are conflicting `MySQL` and `MySQLi`. Use `MySQLi`

```
$date1 = "21-08-2015";
$date2 = "d-m-Y";
$message = $data['status_message'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) as jumlahdata FROM message_complaint WHERE (status_message='$message') AND (time_message BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

> **`$con` equal to [mysqli connection](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp)**

Comment: is there a problem if i using mysql?\

Comment: **MySQL extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.**